# 0auth2 PowerShell headers for API call

Tags: json, api, powershell, oauth-2.0

I wrote a PS function to grab a new Oauth2 access key on the fly which works successfully. I parse the response to grab just the new access key and store it in a variable. Lets call that variable $accesskey

I run the following

```
Invoke-RestMethod "https://mysite.example.com/manage/v5/users" -Method GET -Headers @{"Authorization"="Bearer $accesskey"} -ContentType "application/json"
```

However, I receive the following error

```
Invoke-RestMethod : {"name":"Unauthorized","message":["Your request was made with invalid credentials."],"code":0,"status":401}
```

Or

```
Function Get-APIHeader {


$Uri = "https://mysite.example.com/oauth2/token"

# Set body 
$Body = @{
    grant_type = 'password'
    username = 'user'
    password = 'password'
    client_id = 'test'
    client_secret = '0123456789abcdefghijk'
    scope = 'api'
    redirect_uri = 'https://mysite.example.com/'
}

    $APIResponse = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri $Uri -Body $Body

   @{
    'Authorization' = 'Bearer ' + $APIResponse.access_token
}

}
```

My question is, do I need to store any other information in the header? In order to grab the access key in the first place from my function I have to pass my client id/secret and api username/password information and that is successful.

Thank you

Comment: Could you share your code that grabs the access token? Did you state a ressource in your request for the token? Can you replicate things in postman?

Comment: Thank you for your response. I added the function to the original post. I get the exact same 401 error in postman.